# How should I remove these taps

Tags: plumbing, sink, taps

I have a leaking tap, but I’m unsure how to get these taps off. I’m conscious of not using too much force in case I’m doing it wrong and just damage the tap

[image]

Comment: did you try to unscrew the handle end ... there is a definite seam

Comment: @jsotola yeah I unscrewed it but just looks like you can but different handles in and doesn’t pertain to being able to get to the leaking handle problem

Comment: did you look for a set screw inside the  handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a MOEN faucet, I have the same type. If you are the original owner of the faucet they will usually supply parts and advice free. To remove the handle, twist the vertical round part between the horizontal handle and the sink. It will unscrew and reveal the inside parts that you need to replace.